# Suming multiple colums in a single MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

```
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| exam_id | student_id | subject_id | assignment_mark_total | test_mark_total | exams_mark_obtained |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|       1 |         19 |          1 |                    20 |              30 |                  50 |
|       1 |         20 |          1 |                    18 |              27 |                  48 |
|       1 |         21 |          1 |                    16 |              27 |                  49 |
|       1 |         22 |          1 |                    16 |              29 |                  47 |
|       1 |         23 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         24 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         25 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         26 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         27 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         28 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         29 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         30 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         31 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         32 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         33 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         34 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         35 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         36 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         37 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         38 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       1 |         39 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         19 |          1 |                    20 |              21 |                  49 |
|       2 |         20 |          1 |                    20 |              21 |                  50 |
|       2 |         21 |          1 |                    16 |              27 |                  46 |
|       2 |         22 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         23 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         24 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         25 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         26 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         27 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         28 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         29 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         30 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         31 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         32 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         33 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         34 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         35 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         36 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         37 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         38 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       2 |         39 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         19 |          1 |                     0 |              27 |                  36 |
|       3 |         20 |          1 |                     0 |              24 |                  41 |
|       3 |         21 |          1 |                     0 |              25 |                  48 |
|       3 |         22 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         23 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         24 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         25 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         26 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         27 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         28 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         29 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         30 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         31 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         32 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         33 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         34 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         35 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         36 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         37 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         38 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
|       3 |         39 |          1 |                     0 |               0 |                   0 |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
63 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hello, i have a sample database for a school report sheet,i want to be able to get an array result with sum total of individual subjects for the 3 terms

i will like to have a result like this, as a sum total of each subject's `(assignment_mark_total + test_mark_total + exams_mark_obtained)` AS scores where `exam_id` =1&2&3

```
+--------+
| scores |
+--------+
|    253 |
|    249 |
|    254 |
|     92 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
|      0 |
+--------+
```

Comment: Please explain your logic better, how did you get to this results?

Comment: @sagi thanks for the reply, i didnt get that result, i was hoping to show the result i am expecting

Comment: I understand that, what I dont understand is how to get to this numbers? What is the logic

Comment: @sagi it depends on which number results you are asking about but the numbers displayed are a sumup of 3 exams result per subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for total marks, across the 3 exams, for each student. Try this query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(assignment_mark_total + test_mark_total + exams_mark_obtained) AS scores
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    exam_id in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY 
    student_id
```

You might also want to add **student_id** in the selected column list.

Comment: thanks for the response it worked for me, i especially liked the formating

Answer (score 0):

Try with the query. I think this might help you.

```
select sum(assignment_mark_total + test_mark_total + exams_mark_obtained) as  scores
        where exam_id = 1 or exam_id = 2 or exam_id = 3
            group by student_id;
```

If you want to sort results with the value of student_id then follow this query

```
select sum(assignment_mark_total + test_mark_total + exams_mark_obtained) as  scores
        where exam_id = 1 or exam_id = 2 or exam_id = 3
            group by student_id
                  order by student_id asc;
```

Comment: thanks for your timely response, i have to add the from table but it worked for me.